# Undecidable cardinality

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples, cardinals, decidability

Let $S$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that the existence of $S$ can be proved within ZFC (and in particular the definition of $S$ does not invoke the *negation of the continuum hypothesis*), but the cardinality of $S$ is undecidable within ZFC.

Are there some concrete examples of such sets?

I.e. something more constructive than $S:=$ *some subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$?*

This question results from musing about intuitively obvious equivalents of $\neg CH$ in order to find evidence against the validity of $CH$. My (undoubtedly too optimistic) thinking was that if some such example of $S$ is concrete enough, it would be perhaps intuitively obvious whether it should be countable or continuum, despite this being undecidable formally.

My best guess for the moment is something along the lines of

$$S=\left\{\sum_n\frac{1}{a_n}:\; (a_n)\;\text{is a strictly increasing sequence of primes}\right\}$$

but surely the cardinality can be determined (though not quite sure how).

Comment: The existence of $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid\sf CH\}$ is provable in ZFC, but if CH fails, the set is empty and if CH holds it's the entire real line.

Comment: Yes, I just realised precisely that and edited to make clear what I mean.

Comment: Your set has cardinality continuum. In fact, $S=\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @Wojowu: how do you prove that? I only see that $S$ is unbounded.

Comment: Briefly, fix $x>0$. Pick $a_n$ inductively so that it's the smallest prime above $a_{n-1}$ such that the sum $1/a_1+\dots+1/a_n<x$. You can show that the sum of this series is $x$ because the sum of prime reciprocals diverges.

Comment: @Wojowu: how do I know that the sum of this series converges to $x$ and not just something below $x$?

Comment: Notation: For a subsequence $(a_{n_i})_i$ let $S(k)=\sum_{i=1}^k1/a_i.$ Let $n(1)$ be the least $m$ such that $1/a_m<x$. For any $k, $ if  $S(k)<x$ then let $n(k+1)$ be the least $n>n(k)$ such that $1/a_n+S(k)<x.$ Now consider the least $m\in \Bbb N$ such that $S(k+1)+\sum_{j=1}^m 1/a_{j+n(k+1)}\ge x$... Note  $m$ exists because$ \sum_n 1/a_n=\infty$...Then $n(k+j)=j+n(k+1)$ for $0\le j\le m-1.$ And we have $S(k+m)<x \le S(k+m)+1/a_{n(k+m)+1} $  so  $0<x-S(k+m)\le 1/a_{n(k+m)+1}<1/a_k.$  So $S(k)\to x.$

Comment: MAJOR TYPO in the 1st line of my previous comment.  $S(k$) is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^k 1/a_{n_i}\;$...............BTW. If $(b_n)_n$ is any sequence of positive reals converging to $0$ and $\sum_n b_n=\infty$ then for any $x>0$ there is a subsequence $(b_{n_j})_j$  such that $\sum_j b_{n_j}=x$ by the method of my previous comment.

Comment: Yes, convinced. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your question.

1. Invoking undecidable statements does not mean that the existence of the set is not provable. We can define $S=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid\sf CH\}$ which is empty if $\sf CH$ fails, and is the whole set of real numbers if it holds.
2. What does it mean to decide the cardinality of a set? Surely saying that the cardinality is the same as that of the real numbers *is* something decisive. Indeed, $S$ that you suggestion satisfies that, even though it is not a set of real numbers, as some of these sums do not converge.

   What you mean want to argue is that the index of the $\aleph$ cardinal is decidable. That is something more concrete, but then $\Bbb R$ itself is an example for a set which provably exist and we cannot say much more than that.
3. If you do accept $2^{\aleph_0}$ as "a good answer for cardinality", then it seems to me that you're actually asking whether or not we can *define* a set of real numbers whose cardinality is $\aleph_1$. To that the answer is "depends on what you mean by that". Define in what sense? In the set theoretic universe? With parameters? With real numbers and ordinals as parameters? Define with a predicative definition?

   These answers tend to end up with different answers. But it is consistent with $\sf ZFC$ that every projective set is either countable or of size $2^{\aleph_0}$, which may or may not be larger than $\aleph_1$. Since projective sets are what we might "normally think of" when we think about definable sets of real numbers, this shows that the answer to your question is more or less "no, we cannot explicitly construct a projective set of reals of cardinality $\aleph_1$ in $\sf ZFC$".

   The proof is not at all trivial, and it does require some large cardinal assumptions. If you move away from projective sets, you start getting a bit messier answers (e.g. it can be trivial in the sense that every set is definable from itself as a parameter).

Comment: I swear I have once asked a question along the lines: is it possible to have a model $M$ of $ZFC+\neg CH$ in which every set of reals definable without parameters is countable or has size continuum in $M$? (note we are talking about the model externally, so we can speak about definability) but I cannot for my life find this question... do you happen to know the answer to that?

Comment: @Wojowu: PFA implies that every projective set has a perfect subset. And every set of reals definable from a real parameter is projective.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the last claim?

Comment: Not off hand. If my memory serves me right, you can reflect the definition to $H(\omega_2)$ or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. 1.+2. are not a big deal I guess, but 3. is a good point. Not a set theorist, so won't be trying to specify, but how about "can you give a concrete (i.e. arising from a series, polynomial etc) example of a real subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$ such that the definition (but not necessarily the cardinality proof) could be understood by an undergraduate student"?

Comment: @Damian: You can't. That's the point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Did you mean that every set of reals definable from a real parameter is projective *again assuming PFA*? Because this is false for instance assuming $V=L$, as then you can define the $L$-least non-projective set of reals.

Comment: So whatever infinite set I write down by using down-to-earth concrete mathematical objects, ZFC will be able to prove that it's either countable or continuum? That's not clear to me at all.

Comment: @Damian: Almost anything "down-to-earth" that you'd write is Borel, and probably $\Sigma^0_4$ or less.

Comment: @DamianReding The proof that $L=V$ entails $CH$ is worth a look; it will provide you with an example of a subset of the reals which a particular model would swear is uncountable.

Comment: @Asaf: Not doubting this in the least. But I don't see why some sort of irregularity within the natural numbers could not possibly be used to actually write down some exotic, but concrete $S$, the cardinality of which ends up being undecidable. I wouldn't be at all surpised if it can not, but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @Damian: If it were clear, it wouldn't have taken decades of research by very smart people, would it?

Comment: @Wojowu: Well, at least assuming PFA, then. (The easy proof is to use the fact that PFA implies AD in L(R), and every set in L(R) is definable with a real parameter, and every projective set *is* in L(R).)

Comment: Well, while I 100% agree with everything you say, I am not yet convinced that the question is entirely pointless.

Comment: @Damian: Well, go ahead. Study this. It will take you a couple of years, and by the end you'd be a set theorist. Join us, it's great. We have very nice conferences!

Comment: Already sold my soul to graph theory, can't help amateuring around in set theory though ;)

Comment: @DamianReding You might want to look at a proof of "every Borel (even analytic) set is countable or has the size of the continuum". This should not take too long to understand.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow your argument. First, I disagree that every element of L(R) is definable from a real parameter (take a model more ordinals than reals, then there just aren't enough definitions). Second, this seems to imply that every projective set is definable from a real parameter, not the other way around.

Comment: @Wojowu: It's late, and I'm tired. I might be confusing things. But you seem to get where I'm going at. I hope that you see why this answers your original question, though.

Comment: @Wojowu under PFA there can be (parameterfree) definable sets of reals of size $\aleph_1$, as such a thing can be coded into the GCH pattern without destroying PFA. Though, there cannot be such a set definable (with parameters) over $H_{\omega_1}$. If I remember correctly, you can force with $\mathbb P_{max}$ over $L(\mathbb R)$ (under the assumption of AD there). In the extension ZFC+$2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$ holds and $HOD_{\mathbb R}=L_(\mathbb R)$ (by homogeneity ,note that you dont add reals). Thus every  set of reals definable from reals and ordinals has the perfect set property.

Comment: @AndreasLietz Thank you for the reply. However, correct me if I'm wrong, the last part of your comment concerns sets of reals which are (hereditarily) *ordinal definable* from reals, but I don't think every definable set is ordinal definable.

Comment: @Wojowu sorry this definability thing is confusing. I meant sets of reals that have a definition only using ordinals and reals as parameters.